# Apply AngularJS directive (ui-scrollfix) conditionally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll, sticky, angularjs-ui-utils

I'm using ui-scrollfix directive from UI.Utils to make so called sticky header. It works fine. 
There are two headers in the app. Main one is constantly on the page and second one appears only in certain pages.

```
<div id="main-header" ui-scrollfix></div>

<div id="second-header" ui-scrollfix></div>
```

What I need to do is that `ui-scrollfix` directive was added or applied to `main-header`, if `second-header` is present.

Is that possible to achieve?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think should do this by wrapping both headers in a directive say `headers`. And then in the said directive query for the second header, if it exists then apply the `ui-scrollfix` directive to it.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="aController">
    <div headers>
        <div id="main-header"> main header </div>
        <div id="second-header" ui-scrollfix> second header </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('aController', ['$scope', function (scope) {
}]).directive('uiScrollfix', [function () { // this is just to check that the directive is applied to the element
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.on('click', function () {
                console.log(el[0].textContent);
            });
        }
    }
}]).directive('headers', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            var directiveEl = el[0],
                mainHeaderEl = directiveEl.querySelector('#main-header'),
                secondHeaderEl = directiveEl.querySelector('#second-header'),
                $mainHeaderEl = angular.element(mainHeaderEl);

            if (secondHeaderEl) {
                $mainHeaderEl.attr('ui-scrollfix', '');
                $compile($mainHeaderEl)(scope);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/b1oy729m/)**